# How I can get a listner implementation in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity (AuthenticationActivity) on Android with an interface. Another class implements this interface. I need to parse an interface object for AuthenticationActivity so when one event happens, another class performs an action.

```
public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_webview);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
            mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www....");
        }

    private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith(App.callbackUrl)) {
                    String urls[] = url.split("=");
                    // listener.onComplete(urls[1]); // HERE I NEED FOR LISTNER
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
    }

    public interface OAuthDialogListener {
            public abstract void onComplete(String accessToken);
            public abstract void onError(String error);
        }
    }
```

I have in other class:

```
OAuthDialogListener listener = new OAuthDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String code) {
                getAccessToken(code);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                mListener.onFail("Authorization failed");
            }
        };
```

ann this class call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyWebViewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

how the `MyWebViewActivity` clas uses `listener`?

Comment: Can you post code sample which you have?

Comment: @IshanFernando was made.

Comment: Did you tried startActivityForResult in android ?https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside OAuthWebViewClient class initialize the OAuthDialogListener and them implement it with MyWebViewActivity

try

```
 public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity implements OAuthWebViewClient {
```